# Connect serial port with Android phone

Tags: java, android, serial-port

I have a simple PIC a board  with RS232 ( FTDI).
I connect with  **Bord + USB OTG cable + Samsung S2 microusb port**.

(andriod v 4.1.2)
I want connect 192008 N 1 protocol and use Rx Tx simple comminication.
So cant find short and simple code.

I reserached a lot of code. its very mixed.

Please help me. 
Please send to me simple and shor code...

Thank you for your helps....

I am here... START point.

manifest is ....
   `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" android:required="true"></uses feature>`

activity....

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
 </intent-filter>

 <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />`
```